# Ubuntu cannot log in as root - thinks root is a program

Tags: permissions, root, phpmyadmin, xampp

I originally had problems installing xampp so I installed apache, php, mysql and phpmyadmin via terminal - phpmyadmin did not work - then I discovered I could login as root and install xampp - so I uninstalled but then could no longer log in as root - so I googled and found a suggestion to install root - but root apparently is also program which I then uninstalled - so now when I try and log in as root it says program not found and I cannot log in as root
any assistance greatly appreciated - thanks guys

As requested exact error message in terminal when I enter 'root' is-

The program 'root' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install root-system-bin

whereas before it used to take me into root user or as I understand it 'bash' or # prompt

Comment: Please add more information including the exact error message.

Comment: Simply entering `root` at the command line would not have logged you in as root (perhaps you are thinking of entering `root` at the **login prompt** of a virtual terminal?). To get a root shell, use `sudo -i` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try `sudo su` from your host account. You can verify it by `echo $USER` or `whoami` ?